# Как присвоить названию переменной js значение серверной переменной?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
const elDays+'@m1.gameid' = document.querySelector('.timer-2 .timer__days');
```

Как сделать так чтобы получилась некоторая переменная например если значение `@m1.gamei` = 4,
то получалось `const elDays4 = document.querySelector('.timer-2 .timer__days');`

Answer (score 0):

```
@string varName = "elDays" + m1.gameid;
const @varName = document...
```

Comment: не работает, elDays@m1.gameid  js расценивает как название переменной